# Передача данных между классами objC

Tags: objective-c, ios

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста расставить все точки над i в голове насчет того как передать данные между классами в objc. Правильно ли я понимаю что для того чтоб передать переменную var из из класса OClass1 в OClass2 нужно сделать следующее:

- создать переменную var в OClass1
- написать функцию в OClass1.m которая будет возвращать переменную var: +(тип_var) getVar {return var;}
- добавить в OClass1.h +(тип_var) getVar
- импортировать в OClass2 OClass1.h #import "OClass1.h"
- обращаться из OClass2 к этой функции так: var2=[OClass1 getVar];

Все или я что-то забыл?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем:

> - создать переменную var в OClass1
> - написать функцию в OClass1.m которая будет возвращать переменную 
>   var: +(тип_var) getVar {return var;}
> - добавить в OClass1.h +(тип_var) getVar

Вместо этого можно просто объявит свойство, сеттер и геттер ему подставится на этапе сборки проекта, а вам меньше кода писать

> - импортировать в OClass2 OClass1.h #import "OClass1.h"

Если OClass1 вам нужен только в имплементации класса, то можно там и хедер подключить.

> - обращаться из OClass2 к этой функции так: var2=[OClass1 getVar];

А вот тут совсем мимо - [OClass1 getVar] это обращение к методу класса, а не объекта, а для него не доступны все эти ivar и property ибо они относятся как раз к объекту. Хотя судя по заголовку может это вы и хотите сделать, не понятно.